# Is there any way to define custom special characters in HTML?

Tags: javascript, css, html, html-escape-characters

W3 have defined symbols `&mail;` and `&telephone;` in a draft proposal.  I'd like to start using those now, even though they're not yet official.

Is there some way I can define this; e.g. `&telephone; = &#x260e;`?

My guess it it's not possible, and it's not really much of an issue - just curious as being able to create such custom character mappings could be interesting.

http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-wwwicn.html

Comment: The “draft proposal” is a working draft from 1996, written by one person (though a W3C employee). Nothing ever came out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would be really easy to implement this JavaScript.

```
var el=document.getElementById('element');
el.innerHTML=el.innerHTML.replace(/\&telephone\;/g,'&#x260e;').replace(...........
```

It's a much better idea though to do this on the server side.
e.g. in PHP you could use the strreplace($needle,$haystack) function or define a telephone constant.

```
define('telephone','&#x260e');
//...
echo'<span>',telephone,' 001 23456789</span>';
```